# VBA 438 Error - Object doesn't support this property/method

Tags: vba, excel, runtime

I don't have much VBA experience at all, but this is what I'm trying to do (code is below):

I have two sheets- one of dies, one of sales. Each sale has a die it comes from, with a many sales to one die relationship. I'd like to loop through all dies, and within that loop loop through all sales, and compare each of the rows to a set of criteria before outputting them.

```
'All dies have a type and a size. All products have a type and a size. We hope to match them.
Sub searchroute()
Dim x As Integer, y As Integer, z As Integer
x = 0 'for row offset on dies, number
y = 0 'for row offset on sales, item
z = 0 'for later use

Do Until IsEmpty(Worksheets("Dies").a2.Offset(x, 0)) = True
    Do Until IsEmpty(Worksheets("Sales").a2.Offset(y, 0)) = True
        If Worksheets("Dies").i2.Offset(x, 0) = Worksheets("Sales").c2.Offset(y, 0) Or Worksheets("Dies").i2.Offset(x, 0) = "Any" Then
            If Worksheets("Sales").g2.Offset(y, 0) = Worksheets("Dies").j2.Offset(x, 0) Or Worksheets("Dies").j2.Offset(x, 0) = "Any" Then
                'then we've got the same type and size, print output to a cell
                'should figure out how to append, place the whole list in a single cell
            End If
        End If
        y = y + 1
    Loop
    x = x + 1
Loop

End Sub
```

Stepping through this, it pops a 438 error on the first Do Until. I know this is something easy, but my mind is blank.

Thanks in advance for wisdom!

Comment: Why are you tryin to offset the column/rows?

Try 

    `Do Until IsEmpty(Worksheets("Dies").range("A2").Offset(x, 0)) = True`

Or something along he lines of that. Your issue stems from a lack of a range object I think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace `Worksheets("Dies").a2.` with `Worksheets("Dies").Range("a2").`

Same goes for all instances where you are trying to refer to a spcific cell.

Comment: not even close to the stupidest mistake I've ever made... ;-)